# Перебор значений из списка

Tags: python, list

Есть значения `"1 10 11","1 10 12","1 11 12","2 3 4","2 3 5","2 3 6","2 3 7","2 3 8","2 3 9","2 3 10"`

Хочу сделать перебор параметров как чтобы каждые три значения превращались в переменные a,b,c например:

```
line_l = ["1 10 11","1 10 12","1 11 12","2 3 4","2 3 5","2 3 6","2 3 7","2 3 8","2 3 9","2 3 10"]

for line in line_l:
        
        a = 
        b = 
        c =
```

Как их перевести в a,b,c ? При условии что там может быть и 4ре и 5 рядов цифр (тоесть чтобы была возможность сделать a,b,c,d,e к примеру)

Итог:

```
line_l = ["1 10 11","1 10 12","1 11 12","2 3 4","2 3 5","2 3 6","2 3 7","2 3 8","2 3 9","2 3 10"]

for line in line_l:
        
        a = 1
        b = 9
        c = 11
```

Comment: Какие-то странные у вас значения в списке. это строки? если да, то где кавычки. Если нет, то зачем пробелы?

Comment: line_l = [1 9 11, 1 9 12, 1 10 11, 1 10 12, 1 11 12, 2 3 4, 2 3 5, 2 3 6, 2 3 7, 2 3 8] - вот в такое питон не умеет. Это что такое?

Comment: @Valent Обычно так не делается. Для неопределённого количества значений удобней оперировать массивами. Какая конечная цель этих действий? Зачем каждое значение определять в отдельную переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line_l = ["1 10 11","1 10 12","1 11 12","2 3 4","2 3 5","2 3 6","2 3 7","2 3 8","2 3 9","2 3 10"]

for elem in line_l:
     result = elem.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line_l = [(1, 10, 11),  (1, 10, 12),  (1, 11, 12),  (2, 3, 4),  (2, 3, 5),  (2, 3, 6),  (2, 3, 7),  (2, 3, 8),  (2, 3, 9),  (2, 3, 10),]

for a, b, c in line_l:
    print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]